# Comparing two tables based on first column of each and inserting from master table to child table

Tags: r

I'm using: R version 3.2.1. on windows 10 (with `dplyr` package installed)
I have a master table that is entirely full of `NA`.
Here is a pictorial:

```
 Virus    X.7    X.6  
InkLog     NA     NA  
RCrisp     NA     NA  
FCrisp     NA     NA  
ZCrisp     NA     NA
```

I have another table that has the exact same header row and contains some of the values seen in column 1 of above.
Eg:

```
 Virus    X.7    X.6  
InkLog  33.00  22.00    
FCrisp  23.05 111.01
```

This smaller table is always a subset of the master table (in that all values of first column in this smaller table will occur in the first table).

How do I create a row that is a mix of both tables.
ie: it contains values where there are values and NA where there aren't.
This is how it should look in the end:

```
 Virus    X.7    X.6  
InkLog  33.00  22.00    
RCrisp     NA     NA  
FCrisp  23.05 111.01  
ZCrisp     NA     NA
```

Any pointers much appreciated. Also, would this be an efficient way to create tables that contain NA's where they don't contain data (as gauged from the universe of data from the master table)

Comment: just `rbind(data, data)` remove duplicates `data[!duplicated(data$Virus), ]` (and sort `data[order(data$Virus), ]` if you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right approach was posted by rawr, but just for completeness’ sake:

Base package:

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, all =TRUE, na.rm =TRUE )
df[!duplicated(df$Virus),]
```

dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2) %>% arrange(X.7) %>% distinct(Virus)
# or
full_join(df1, df2) %>% filter(!duplicated(Virus, fromLast = TRUE))
```

sqldf:

```
sqldf("SELECT min(Virus) AS Virus, [X.7], [X.6] 
      FROM (SELECT * FROM df2 AS t1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT * FROM df1 AS t2)
      GROUP BY Virus")
```

Output:

```
   Virus   X.7    X.6
1 FCrisp 23.05 111.01
2 InkLog 33.00  22.00
3 RCrisp    NA     NA
4 ZCrisp    NA     NA
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Virus = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("FCrisp", 
"InkLog", "RCrisp", "ZCrisp"), class = "factor"), X.7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA), X.6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Virus", "X.7", 
"X.6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Virus = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("FCrisp", 
"InkLog"), class = "factor"), X.7 = c(33, 23.05), X.6 = c(22, 
111.01)), .Names = c("Virus", "X.7", "X.6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```